# Collapse same-date rows based on max values in a column in R

Tags: r

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
date         x1.   x2.  predict_date 
2022-08-11   21    13   2022-08-12 10:00:00   
2022-08-11   32    NA   2022-08-12 11:00:00
```

For the rows with the same `date` column, I want to collapse the rows into **one row**. I want to get the `x1` column based on the max `predict_date` and then fill in the `x2` column based on the previous row (since it has a non-NA value). The structure is always the same in that the later row will have missing value in `x2.`.

So, the expected output would be:

```
date         x1.   x2.  predict_date 
2022-08-11   32    13   2022-08-12 11:00:00
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the last non-missing value for each date. Assuming the structure is always the same (`x1` never missing and `x2` always missing on last the row), it produces the result you want.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~last(na.omit(.), order_by = predict_date)))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   date         x1.   x2. predict_date       
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1 2022-08-11    32    13 2022-08-12 11:00:00
```